# PhpStorm: loading external files locks up program

Tags: phpstorm

I have a problem using [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm):

All of my sites are hosted externally, and I pull them into my local environment PhpStorm project. When I need to pull in a new project (or sync an old one), it locks up PhpStorm during this process, which could be long. If I want to work on a different PhpStorm project in the meantime, I can't do so via PhpStorm.

Does anyone know how to get around this? If it helps, I'm using Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open feature request from March 2010 to solve this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1307

For now, you may want to consider one of these workarounds:

1. Exclude all folders to prevent an initial download.  Go back into the settings, remove the exclusions, and then do a background sync.
2. Creating the project without defining a remote server.  Go into the project settings, add the server, and configure the folders you'd like to sync.  Then perform a background sync.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I opened up a case with jetBrains about that, the thing is that PhpStorm uses all the CPU at almost 100% until it finish indexing, so this is a big problem with older computers or computers with small resources

Comment: For a complete answer, would you mind adding a link to your request for jetBrains?

Comment: I did that via e-mail with jetbrains support center so I don't have a link